# execute for loop for a dictionary key

Tags: python, django

This kind of data i have sent to my template
x = [{'id': 668, 'title': 'ME2: Pressurisation Unit Maintenance Record', 'valuess': ['person', 'address', 'asset']}

return render(request, 'xyz.html', {'data': x})

want to run a for loop for a key named 'values' in my data set x

"x" is a key but it contains list of values as well. So want to run a for loop on a key "values" How to do this. anyone please help....I just started my programming career...i am stucked plz help me

Comment: Do you mean to run a for loop inside an html template?

Comment: yes...wanna run for loop in my html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either this:

```
{% for d in data %}
    {% for value in d.values %}
        <p>{{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or:

```
{% for d in data %}
    {{ d.values }}
{% endfor %}
```